# How to use the attribute of the foreign key in Django

Tags: django, django-models

Like in this Example, I want to use the category to derive the directory path.

```
class Team_Type(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category

class Team_member(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Team_Type, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='hwc')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.designation
```

Something of the form

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='hwc/'+ category)
```

I have tried using os.path in following ways but no success

```
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=os.path.join('hwc', category.category))
photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=os.path.join('hwc', category.__str__()))
```

This doesn't work since category is a foreignkey and I holds no such attribute. Any alternate solution?

Answer (score 0):

The ForeignKey is a database key that is used to connect 2 tables together. Here we can say that the `category` foreign key is connecting the `Team_Type` and `Team_member` models together by referencing the primary key of model `Team_Type`.

If you don't explicitly define a primary key in your table or model class in Django, then Django automatically creates a default Integer field variable and uses that as the Primary key. Note this that Foreign key in `Team_member` is referencing the primary key in the `Team_Type`.

In your case, the primary key of `Team_Type` model class is an Integer field, that Django makes.
You have to explicitly mention, which variable in the `Team_Type` model should be the primary key and referred by the Foreign key of `Team_member`.

You can do this simply by modifying your code as follows.

```
class Team_Type(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

Now the Foreign key in `Team_member` will have a reference to Primary key of `Team_Type` model, that is the `category` field.